# facebook messaging current_thread does not return psid

Tags: javascript, html, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I am trying to send a request using facebook MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(). I tried sending this API so that it redirects to a new page called schedules.

```
var messageToShare = {
  "attachment":{
    "type":"template",
    "payload":{
      "template_type":"generic",
      "elements": [{
        "title":"Garfield is going to the cinema",
        "image_url": "https://webhookboi.herokuapp.com/schedule",
        "subtitle": "You have been invited to join them, let them know when you are free",
        "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://webhookboi.herokuapp.com/schedule",
              "messenger_extensions": "true",
              "webview_height_ratio": "full",
              "fallback_url": "https://webhookboi.herokuapp.com/schedule"
            },
        "buttons":[{
          "type":"web_url",
          "url":"https://webhookboi.herokuapp.com/schedule",
          "title":"Select Times",
          "messenger_extensions": "true"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

and this is the beginShareFlow() encased inside a submit button listener

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', () => {

            MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(function success(response) {
              if(response.is_sent === true){
                // User shared. We're done here!
                MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
              }
              else{
                // User canceled their share!
                MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
              }
            },
            function error(errorCode, errorMessage) {
            // An error occurred trying to share!
            },
            messageToShare,
            "current_thread");


        });
```

The request will then be intercepted by these in the main javascript

```
app.get('/schedule', (req, res, next) => {
    let referer = req.get('Referer');
    if (referer) {
        if (referer.indexOf('www.messenger.com') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/');
        } else if (referer.indexOf('www.facebook.com') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/');
        }
        res.sendFile('public/schedule.html', {root: __dirname});
    }
});

app.get('/schedulepostback', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.query;
    let response = {
        "text": `Great, you have agreed to watch on ${body.dates} in the ${body.times} at ${body.locations} `
    };


    res.status(200).send('Please close this window to return to the conversation thread.');
    callSendAPI(body.psid, response);
});
```

Here is the main problem, in the snippet below, I tried to call the threads psid again but it never showed.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Set your Schedule</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));
    window.extAsyncInit = () => {
        // TODO: How to parse env file from here?
        MessengerExtensions.getSupportedFeatures(function success(result) {
            let features = result.supported_features;
            if (features.includes("context")) {
                MessengerExtensions.getContext(INPUTED_APP_ID_HERE,
                    function success(thread_context) {
                        // success
                        document.getElementById("psid").value = thread_context.psid;
                        document.getElementById("tid").value = thread_context.tid;
                        
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        // error
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
            }
        },
         function error(err) {
            // error retrieving supported features
            console.log(err);
        });



        var messageToShare = {
            "text": `Your friend requested to watch on`.document.querySelector('input[name="dates"]:checked').value.'in the'.document.querySelector('input[name="times"]:checked').value.'at'.document.querySelector('input[name="locations"]:checked').value
};



        document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', () => {

            MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(function success(response) {
              if(response.is_sent === true){
               // User shared. We're done here!
               MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
              }
              else{
               // User canceled their share!
                MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
              }
            },
            function error(errorCode, errorMessage) {
           // An error occurred trying to share!
            },
            messageToShare,
            "current_thread");


        });
    };
</script>
<form action="/schedulepostback" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="psid" id="psid">
    <input type="text" name="tid" id="tid">
    <h3>Date</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="3 April" checked>3 April<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="4 April">4 April<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="5 April">5 April<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="6 April">6 April<br>
    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="7 April">7 April<br>
    <h3>Time</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="Daytime" checked>Daytime<br>
    <input type="radio" name="times" value="Evening">Evening<br>
    <h3>Location</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="locations" value="Munich" checked>Munich<br>
    <input type="radio" name="locations" value="Berlin">Berlin<br>
    <input type="radio" name="locations" value="Dusseldorf">Dusseldorf<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this because of my template type? or something else? Any help would be appriciated.

**EDIT**

If I click on the chat extension, everything works fine and the messenger extension works which produces this chat postback.

[image: result of the chat extension postback]

However when I click on the "Select Times" button on the postback, the psid doest show. The top Three bars were supposed to display the psid, tid, and object. This also didn't pop up in X-Frame but in a new tab. Any help here?

[image: the result of the select times button]

Comment: What's the value of `thread_context` in the callback when you call `MessengerExtensions.getContext()`?

Comment: for the first call is [object Object] and for the /schedule call nothing shows up, I also tried setting the messenger_extension : true and it doesn't work "shows the page in a new tab rather than xframe" @amuramoto

Comment: Yes, you need to set messenger_extensions: true on the button. Also, have you whitelisted the domain (https://webhookboi.herokuapp.com/) in your Messenger Profile?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted the domain and set the messenger extension to true, but it still pops up in a new tab and doesn't give any psid. I have edited the problem above to show you the screen shots @amuramoto